# iPhone: keep audio recording app running in the background

Tags: iphone, background, avplayer, avaudiorecorder

I have searched for suitable answers to my question but I did not find any helpful so far.
I want to record the decibel in the environment. If a specific threshold is exceeded the app shall play a sound or song file. Everything works fine so far but I have troubles to keep the app running in the background. 
I have already added the attribute "Application does not run in the background" and set its value to "NO". I've read that one should add the "external-accessory" element to the "Required background modes". I added that too but still it does not work.
I am using the `AVAudioRecorder` to record the sound and the `AVPlayer` to play the sound/music file. First I used the `MPMediaController` `iPodMusicPlayer` but it throws an exception along with the attribute "Required background modes".

EDIT:
I am using xCode 4.5 with iOS 6

EDIT 2:
When I add the string viop to the "Required background modes" it seems to continue recording while in background. But it still does not play the music file when being in background. I also tried to add the "audio" value too but it did not help.

EDIT 3:
I've consulted the apples developer reference. It seems like you have to configure your AVAudioSession. With that it seems to work ([link to reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW4%22the%20link%20to%20the%20relevant%20reference%22)). But now I have troubles in playing more than one file because as soon as the first track has finished playing, the app will go into suspended mode again. As far as I know there is no possibility to initialize the AVPlayer or AVAudioPlayer with more than one file. I used the delegate methode audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: to set the next track but it did not work.

EDIT 4: Ok, one possibility is to avoid stopping the recorder, that is removing the [record stop] so that it even records the sound when music is played. It is a work around that works but still I appreciate any other (better) solution to this. A solution that doesn't need to keep the recorder running all the time.

the relevant code:
I initialize everything in the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
lowPassResults = -120.0;
thresholdExceeded = NO;

if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
            levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

    } else {
    NSString* errorDescription = [error description];
    NSLog(errorDescription);
    }
}
```

The levelTimer Callback that is called every 0.03 seconds:

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
//refreshes the average and peak power meters (the meter uses a logarithmic scale, with -160 being complete quiet and zero being maximum input
[recorder updateMeters];

const double ALPHA = 0.05;

float averagePowerForChannel = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0]; 

    //adjust the referential
    averagePowerForChannel = averagePowerForChannel / 0.6;

    //converts the values 
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * averagePowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;   

    float db = lowPassResults + 120;
    db = db < 0? 0: db;

    if(db >= THRESHOLD)
    {
        [self playFile];
    }
}
```

Finally the playFile method which plays the music file:

```
- (void) playFile {

    NSString* title = @"(You came down) For a day";
    NSString* artist = @"Forge";
    NSMutableArray *songItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    MPMediaQuery *loadSongsQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *artistPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:artist forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *titlePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:title forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [loadSongsQuery addFilterPredicate:artistPredicate];
    [loadSongsQuery addFilterPredicate:titlePredicate];

    NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [loadSongsQuery items]; 

    if([itemsFromGenericQuery count])
        [songItemsArray addObject: [itemsFromGenericQuery objectAtIndex:0]];


    if([songItemsArray count])
    {
        MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:songItemsArray];


        if ([collection count]) {

            MPMediaItem* mpItem = [[collection items]objectAtIndex:0];
            NSURL* mediaUrl = [mpItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
            AVPlayerItem* item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:mediaUrl];
            musicPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];

            [musicPlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with my problem? Did I miss anything else?

Comment: I met the same issue with you. Have you got it done？ Could you please share what you have found? Thanks so much

Comment: It is now several months ago but I think I kept the solution I described in my post above (EDIT 4). unfortunately, I do not have the possibility to look up the code again because I do not work at that company anymore where I developed an app with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = 0;
   task=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
   NSLog(@"Expiration handler called %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
   [application endBackgroundTask:task];
   task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];
}
```